# apply error class on bootstrap datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have an input field which has [ui-bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) `datepicker` applied on it. Here is how I am doing it:

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-inline">
      <!--<label>Date</label>-->
      <p class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-class="{error:datepicker.$invalid}" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions"
               name="datepicker" ng-pattern="/^[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$/" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
          </span>
      </p>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="init()" style="margin-bottom: 10px" type="button">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

The pattern works fine, it applies validation on this field, so that it only allows `yyyy-mm-dd` date format. However, In doing so, it does not mark the input field with red borders and disable submit button. What I am doing wrong here?